# How can mindfulness be maintained while receiving and processing information?

Tags: mindfulness

It seems that when I process information, be it at work or with people in general, I struggle to not be swept into a cerebral/cognitive space. How can this be remedied/avoided?

Comment: Hello and welcome to Buddhism SE. We also have a [*Help Center*](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/help) with useful resources that you might like. Enjoy your time here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At different points throughout your day, try moving your feet, wiggling your toes, knocking one foot on another, until you regain good awareness of your lower body. Also try to push your lower abdomen out.

In general, try to get in the habit of watching various parts of your body, stretch them, put them in comfortable positions. Neck, legs, waist, diaphragm, face muscles - everything. The more you recover awareness of your body, the better your connection with emotional/subconscious mind will be.

My Zen Master called this "coming downstairs" (from one's head to one's body and heart)

Answer (score 1):

Warren, what is your intention in practising "mindfulness"? There is nothing wrong with thinking especially when you receive information. If you want to quiten the mental chatter , you have to practise formal meditation daily, because if you are developed in this you can, with few attempts, shut off a lot of thinking by an act of will. As a beginner it is better to start a small meditation session, seeing and remembering the various benefits that mindfulness entails and making it a habit. Slowing one's behaviours down (walking speed, speech, eating pace...) can all act like cues so that mindfulness re-occurs. Secular mindfulness, usually taught by Jon Kabar Zinn, is kind of just experiencing and savoring the moment, one's pains and emotions and for stress reduction (MBSR - Mindfulness Based Stress Reduction). In cognitive behaviour therapies it is employed to become more aware of thoughts and emotions and then to either challenge these thoughts or with a curious attitude let them drift away (Zinn mentions beginner's mind and acceptance for example as basic attitudes). In Buddhism, however, mindfulness (sati-sampajañña) has a variety of uses. It is used to remember (sati) certain teachings (dhammas), apply situational wisdom (sampajañña) due to the "rememberance" (sati), developing the 4 satipatthanas (4 foundations of mindfulness: Body, feelings, Thoughts and Phenomena), developing concentration to penetrate meditation subjects so that the mind sticks at the object/subject. Due to the concentration, the mind becomes calm and  can do the thinking/concentration without getting carried away by other thoughts, noises et cetera unrelated to the meditation. One more thing: Since mindfulness or concentration seems to be important for you, Buddhism teaches us that morality and one's positive emotions give rise to more concentration. If one is always angry, anxious, jealous etc. your mind will be restless and sleepy quite quickly.